# template formatting - allow readable format

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I'm creating some apache velocity templates and formatting the code(intellij Idea) breaks the template, because the text parts of the template are automatically indented.
When there's only a single line of the output text, then the indent is not preserved in the output:

```
#macro(body)
    #if(${someCondition})
    Hello
    #end
#end
```

The output is:

```
Hello
```

The problem with multiline text output is this:

```
#macro(body)
    #if(${someCondition})
    Hello
    World
    #end
#end
```

And the output:

```
Hello
    World
```

Is there some way to strip the indent of the text part based on the sorrounding code? I'd like to avoid ugly formatted templates like this:

```
#macro(body)
    #if(${someCondition})
Hello
World
    #end
#end
```

The code which uses the template:

```
final VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.init();
final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
//put variables into context
engine.evaluate(context, outputWriter, "LOG", inputString);
```

Maybe there's something I can put into VelolocityContext, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I had this problem as well, I think the only solution is to avoid formatting this file, or format it manually.

Comment: The only problem is that the template is ugly, but I think I can live with it :( Thx